# how to import Bool value from server in objective -c

Tags: objective-c, parsing, xml-parsing

My code do parsing with server:

```
-(instancetype)initWithKey:(NSData *)key keyId:(NSString *)keyId validityStart:(NSDate *)validityStart validityEnd:(NSDate *)validityEnd support_long_messages:(NSString *)support_long_messages
{
}
```

the support_long_messages arrive from server true or false, I can see that from debug but I dont know how to unwrap this value to write if else statement like:

```
  if (!_support_long_messages) {

            [self showAlert];

        }
```

when I write the if statement, it doesn't work.
I want that if it is false show the UIAlertview if it is true no.

Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `boolValue` property of NSString

```
if (![_support_long_messages boolValue]) {

            [self showAlert];

        }
```

From declaration of boolValue property in NSString header file

> @property (readonly) BOOL boolValue NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);  // Skips
>   initial space characters (whitespaceSet), or optional -/+ sign
>   followed by zeroes. Returns YES on encountering one of "Y", "y", "T",
>   "t", or a digit 1-9. It ignores any trailing characters.

Answer (score 0):

If the `support_long_messages` arrive from server true or false, then you shouldn't take it as `NSString` variable , try with it as `BOOL` variable like as under.

```
-(instancetype)initWithKey:(NSData *)key
                     keyId:(NSString *)keyId
             validityStart:(NSDate *)validityStart
               validityEnd:(NSDate *)validityEnd
     support_long_messages:(BOOL)support_long_messages{

}
```

And then try

```
if (!_support_long_messages) {
      [self showAlert];
 }
```